# jQuery-UI Droppable "out" option firing on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I've created a drag and drop quiz using jQuery UI. Answers are dragged into boxes, an array is updated with the answer, and when a button is pressed the score is calculated from the contents of the array.

If the user wishes to change their answer, they can drag it from the box. The droppable 'out' option removes the contents from the array.

However, if a box is already populated, and an answer is dragged over it, the 'out' option is fired and the content of the array location removed.

**To recreate the issue:**
1. Drag a couple of answers into the correct boxes (the final two answers are "command" and "line" respectively)
2. Click the "check" button -- it will show your score to be "2" (which is correct)
3. Drag one of your answers over the other and back to its original location without releasing the mouse until it's back in its original location.
4. Click the "check" button again -- it will show your score to be "1"

The problem is occurring because the "out" option is registering the mouse-out of anything dragged over it, even if it's not being dropped on it.

```
out: function(event, ui) {
     var parent = $(this).attr("id");
     var child = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
     removefromlist(parent, child);
     $(this).removeClass("full");
}
```

Any help gratefully received. Here's my Code:

```js
$(function() {

  var position;

  // Actions for draggable object
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    start: function() {
      // Get start position. Object will return to this if drop is rejected
      position = $(this).offset();
    }
  });

  // Actions for droppable area
  $(".droppable").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    //Event to accept a draggable when dropped on the droppable
    drop: function(event, ui) {

      // Check if the droppable already has a draggable in it.
      // If so, move the draggable back to its last position.
      if ($(this).hasClass("full")) {
        $(ui.draggable).animate({
          "left": position.left + "px",
          "top": position.top + "px"
        }, 300);
      } else {
        // Snap the draggable into position
        ui.draggable.position({ of: $(this),
          my: 'left top',
          at: 'left top'
        });
        // Add a class to flag that droppable has a draggable.
        $(this).addClass("full");
        var parent = $(this).attr("id");
        var child = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
        addtolist(parent, child);
      }
    },

    //Event to remove a draggable when dragged outside the droppable
    out: function(event, ui) {
      var parent = $(this).attr("id");
      var child = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
      removefromlist(parent, child);
      $(this).removeClass("full");
    }
  });



});



// NO NEED TO WORRY ABOUT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE //



// Keeps a list of which elements have been dropped into which position

var totalAnswers = $(".droppable").length;
var droplist = new Array;

for (var i = 0; i < totalAnswers; i++) {
  droplist.push(-1);
  console.log(droplist[i]);
}

// Add dropped elements and parents to the array
function addtolist(parent, child) {
  console.log("ADD Received: " + parent + child);

  var convertedParent = parseInt(parent.substr(4));
  //console.log(convertedParent);

  var convertedChild = parseInt(child.substr(3));
  convertedChild = (convertedChild / 10) - 5;
  //console.log(convertedChild);

  droplist[convertedParent] = convertedChild;
  console.log(convertedParent + " : " + droplist[convertedParent]);
}

// Remove elements from the array
function removefromlist(parent, child) {
  console.log("REM Received: " + parent + child);

  var convertedParent = parseInt(parent.substr(4));

  droplist[convertedParent] = -1;
  console.log(convertedParent + " : " + droplist[convertedParent]);
}

function allAnswered(questions) {
  if (questions === droplist.length) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "All questions answered. Press the button to find out how many are correct.";
    document.getElementById("checkButton").style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    var remaining = questions - droplist.length;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = remaining + " more to answer";
    //document.getElementById("checkButton").style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}

function checkAnswers() {
  // For now, this lists the contents of the array
  console.log("CHECKING");
  var score = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < droplist.length; i++) {
    console.log(i + " / " + droplist[i]);

    if (i === droplist[i]) {
      score++;
    }

  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "You scored " + score;
}
```

```css
.clear {
  clear: both;
}

#textarea {
  position: absolute;
  top: 450px;
}

#checkButton {
  /*visibility: hidden;*/
}

.questiontext {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/* Drag and drop objects */

.draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 21px;
  float: left;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px #ddf solid;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: move;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.droppable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dotted #ddd;
  margin: 0 10px -10px 10px;
}

.full {
  border: #aaecff solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="questiontext">The operating system provides an
    <div class="droppable ui-widget-header" id="drop1"></div> which allows the user to interact with the computer.
    <div class="droppable ui-widget-header" id="drop2"></div>
    <div class="droppable ui-widget-header" id="drop3"></div> Interfaces (
    <div class="droppable ui-widget-header" id="drop4"></div>) provide a visual, user-friendly way to use the system. They are often optimised for specific
    <div class="droppable ui-widget-header" id="drop5"></div> methods, such as touchscreens which use finger gestures. Prior to this, they were typically WIMP (
    <div class="droppable ui-widget-header" id="drop6"></div>,
    <div class="droppable ui-widget-header" id="drop7"></div>,
    <div class="droppable ui-widget-header" id="drop8"></div>,
    <div class="droppable ui-widget-header" id="drop9"></div>) based.</div>
  <div class="questiontext">A
    <div class="droppable ui-widget-header" id="drop10"></div>
    <div class="droppable ui-widget-header" id="drop11"></div> Interface (CLI) is text-based. They are not as user-friendly as GUI interfaces, but use less resources, making them more efficient and powerful
  </div>
  <div class="draggable ui-widget-content" id="ans60">interface</div>
  <div class="draggable ui-widget-content" id="ans70">Graphical</div>
  <div class="draggable ui-widget-content" id="ans80">User</div>
  <div class="draggable ui-widget-content" id="ans90">GUI</div>
  <div class="draggable ui-widget-content" id="ans100">input</div>
  <div class="draggable ui-widget-content" id="ans110">Windows</div>
  <div class="draggable ui-widget-content" id="ans120">Icons</div>
  <div class="draggable ui-widget-content" id="ans130">Menu</div>
  <div class="draggable ui-widget-content" id="ans140">Pointer</div>
  <div class="draggable ui-widget-content" id="ans150">Command</div>
  <div class="draggable ui-widget-content" id="ans160">Line</div>
</div>
<div id="textarea">
  <p id="output" class="clear">Output</p>
  <button type="button" onClick="checkAnswers();" id="checkButton">Check</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the current id on the start event.

```
$(function() {

  var position;
  var currentChild;

  // Actions for draggable object
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
      // Get start position. Object will return to this if drop is rejected
      position = $(this).offset();
      var child = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
    }
  });

  // Actions for droppable area
  $(".droppable").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    //Event to accept a draggable when dropped on the droppable
    drop: function(event, ui) {

      // Check if the droppable already has a draggable in it.
      // If so, move the draggable back to its last position.
      if ($(this).hasClass("full")) {
        $(ui.draggable).animate({
          "left": position.left + "px",
          "top": position.top + "px"
        }, 300);
      } else {
        // Snap the draggable into position
        ui.draggable.position({ of: $(this),
          my: 'left top',
          at: 'left top'
        });
        // Add a class to flag that droppable has a draggable.
        $(this).addClass("full");
        var parent = $(this).attr("id");
        var child = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");

          addtolist(parent, child);

      }
    },

    //Event to remove a draggable when dragged outside the droppable
    out: function(event, ui) {
      var parent = $(this).attr("id");
      var child = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
      if (child == currentChild) {
        removefromlist(parent, child);
      }
      $(this).removeClass("full");
    }
  });



});
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. However, currentChild's value is undefined. Whilst this overcomes the problem of any draggable firing any "out" option, it does not remove the array data when a draggable is actually removed from a parent.